# Grails set language (internationalization) via URL mappin

Tags: url, grails, internationalization

I'm interested in supporting English and French in my Grails app with user-friendly URL.

format: /appname/language/controller/action

example: /store/en/product/list

What is the best way without passing as a parameter (?lang=fr) then rewriting the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following mapping in your *appname\grails-app\conf\UrlMappings.groovy* should do it.

```
"/$lang/$controller/$action?/$id?"{

}
```

See the [URL mapping](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) article on the grails website for details.